# Bootstrap - form elements of unequal width occupying a full .row

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

I have a Bootstrap 3.3.7 project which features a search facility consisting of 3 text input fields.

The 3 inputs are placed inside `.col-md-4` such that they occupy the full width of the screen. Example here: https://jsfiddle.net/8vm8m8za/6/

I have a requirement to put a button in on the right hand side (after "Field 3" on the example above). The text on this button is a single character ("A") and therefore the button doesn't take up much width. I've updated the fiddle to show how it looks: https://jsfiddle.net/8vm8m8za/7/. To get this working I changed `.col-md-4` to `.col-md-3` as I understand they need to add up to 12 to take up the full width of the `.row`

The effect I want is between the 2 example links I posted. I want the 3 text inputs to take up all the width, but also include the button on the same row and "adjust" (don't know how else to describe it) the width such that it all fits neatly into 1 `.row`.

I can't understand how to implement this with Bootstrap as I believe everything has to add up to 12 to get it to take up the full row.

Comment: use input-group-addon on the last input field.

Comment: It is not mandatory to that everything has to sum up to 12, you can use anything less then 12 and the items will align in a row, if the values goes above 12 it will take the next line.

Comment: is this what are you looking for  https://jsfiddle.net/DChandraShekhar/8vm8m8za/8/

Comment: @ChandraShekhar that's almost exactly what I want. I want the button ("A") to appear as it's own input though - on your example it looks attached to "Field 3". I'd like the same amount of spacing between all 4 elements.

Answer (score 1):

Hi I am not exactly sure is this what you are requesting for..

Try this make the first two field sets to `.col-md-4` then the third to `.col-md-3` and place the button in `.col-md-1`that would make up the grid complete.

check this [link js fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/kuladeep/684yuoe0/)

Comment: Ideally i wanted the 3 text inputs to be the same width though. it's hard to explain but I'm looking for something that's just like the first example I posted, but with the button at the end on the same row and for everything to just fit